# How can I store nested json data in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I have 3 models:

```
class Depot < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :car_amounts
    has_many :cars, :through => :car_amounts
end

class CarAmount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :depot
  belongs_to :car
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :car_amounts
  has_many :depots, :through => :car_amounts
end
```

What is the best way to store json paramers, which contains depot, amounts and cars data. Something like this:

```
{
"Depots": {
    "title": "Dealer1"
},
"Amounts": [
    {
        "amount": "1"
        "car": [
            {
                "Type": "supercar1"
            }
         ]
    }, 
    {
        "amount": "5"
        "car": [
            {
                "Type": "supercar2"
            }
         ]
    }, 

   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a little unclear what your question is, but I think you might be looking for `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. The documentation can be found here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html. From the documentation:

> Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records through the parent.

As an example, you could add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :cars` in you `Depots` model. While it wouldn't quite work with the JSON you've shown above, it works well with the general idea.

If this isn't quite your question then please comment and I will clarify.

Answer (score -1):

If this data needs to be in you your database then I would 'seed' the data and import it into  your database. You can create a file db/seed.rb and lets say I want to import students into my database. I have a student model already created/migrated. In my seed.rb I would do something like...

```
students = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(File.read('db/students.json'))

students.each do |a|
     Student.find_or_create_by_id_number(:id_number => a['id_number'], :username => a['username'], :first_name => a['first_name'], :last_name => a['last_name'])
end
```

...and my students.json looks like...

```
 [
{"id_number": "00xx280","username": "jesxxne","first_name": "Jessie","last_name": "Lane","email": "jesxxane@xx.edu","phone_number": "602-321-6693","is_active": true ,"last_four": "1944" },
{"id_number": "11xx2","username": "jamxxacqua","first_name": "James","last_name": "Bevixxua","email": "jamesbxxacqua@xx.edu","phone_number": "828-400-5393","is_active": true ,"last_four": "5422" }
 ]
```

Now you can run rake db:seed to import this data. Good luck!